# Dynamic Aggregations in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there any framework or API in Java that would help in creating dynamic aggregations over collections just like **QueryBuilder** is used for dynamic query using **find()** in Java?

Comment: You want aggregation in Mongo or in Java?

Comment: I want to perform aggregation dynamically on mongoDB collections using Java programming language.